# Adding child nodes to a node in XML using Linq To excel

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Following is the structure of my XML

```
<Id>
 <Sid> 123 </Sid>
 <Name> Xyz </Name>
 <Name> Abc </Name>
</Id>
<Id>
 <Sid> 789 </Sid>
 <Name> Xyz </Name>
 <Name> Abc </Name>
</Id>
```

I just want to Enter a new child node i.e  Any Name  to the node which is having value Sid = 789.

I have tried this code but its not working.

```
XElement xe = xDoc.Elements().Where(r => (string)r.Element("Sid") == "789").FirstOrDefault();

            xe.Add(new XElement("Name", "Hello"));
```

Since i m new to Linq and Excel ,i am unable to figure it out.

Can anyone please help me to understand this and achieve a postive result.

All sort of help will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use XPath query expression to select element with complex criteria :

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

........
........
XElement xe = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Id[Sid=123]");
xe.Add(new XElement("Name", "Hello"));
```

or without XPath <sup>*</sup> :

```
XElement xe = xDoc.Root.Elements()
                    .Where(r => (string)r.Element("Sid") == "789")
                    .FirstOrDefault();
xe.Add(new XElement("Name", "Hello"));
```

<sup>*)</sup> I assume that `<Id>` elements are direct child of a root node.

Comment: Hi ,thanks for answering so fast,but its showing error

Comment: Its working now ,but no such node is added to the xml

Comment: have you saved the `xDoc` after finished adding elements?

Comment: oh yeah i forgot that

Comment: It created a new element but my whole file got overwritten ,can u help with that too

Comment: I have done this xDoc.Save("path");Is there any other option like append ,i havent found anyhting like that

Comment: There is no such option like append, XDocument load entire XML to memory, and at the time it saved it will replace the file with currently loaded data in memory. Shouldn't be problem if you loaded `xDoc` from existing file, it will keep initial data plus your modification back when it saved.

Comment: i have loaded it from an existing file only